# Image on UITabBar gets squished

Tags: ios, uitabbar

Hey I am using a custom sized UITabBar with extra large images.

I add the images to the tab bar item like this:

```
UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBar;
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    [tabBarItem1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]];
    [tabBarItem1 setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 20, 0)];
```

Also because the images are larger I want them to hover more in the middle of the tab bar, so I add the inset.

My issue is when I program the inset and then click on the button, the button squishes in on its self. It maintains its width, but its height squishes in on its self. I of course don't want this to happen, but I can't seem to find out whats going on.

Thanks, Krtko

-Note for Mods Please lock this thread

-Note for people answering my question. I appreciate your help but it was a known bug at the time, so please stop answering this question. Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you seeing this on iOS 7 only?

7.1 seemed to introduce a bug with tab bar image insets. If you continually tap or hold the tab, it grows or shrinks depending on the insets. If you tap on another tab, the tab bar image goes back to normal right?

Comment: Yeah awe lame, thanks for letting me know. So i already went a head and added a chunk of alpha to the bottom of each icons. Do you think you could help me with something else? Now when I can only click on the about 75% of the buttons. The top portion does not fire and will fire on any subviews under it. I did resize the tab bars frame, but that didn't fix anything. Thanks :)

Comment: @Krtko do not use comments to ask a second question. Instead, ask a new question!

Comment: The only for sure fix I know of so far is to not use insets at all. A friend of mine ended up going that route. I'm holding off to see if they fix this since it does not ruin any functionality. Plus I'm like you, my images are larger and I'm not using titles.

Comment: Man I spent forever on this problem, swearing it was me. You don't know how much you saved me lol. Upvote a million times if i could.

Comment: Just a FYI, I checked and insetting the title does work

Answer (score 11):

When using UIEdgeInsetsMake the important point is to have the top inset "BE EQUAL" to the bottom inset.
For example : item.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);

Comment: This answer fixes the bug for both top/bottom and right/left. The downside is you can't resize the image, just move it around.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your insets for the image. Use an image that is exactly of the size you want. We have to follow this approach till Apple fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may put a UIView on top of the tab bar, and add a UITapGestureReognizer to the UIView. When tapped, I determine where it is and call the appropriate selected item for the tabbar. Hack, but works quite nicely and lets you keep your inset values to whatever you want.

```
 @property UIView  tabBarCover;//place on top of uitabbar and give it clear color background

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   [tabBar setSelectedItem:[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0]];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
                        [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                        action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
   [tabBarCover addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];

 }
```

Then each time the UIView is tapped, set the selected item based on where the user touched. I had 3 tab bar items, so I just did some logic for the x coordinate.

```
-(void) handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) recognizer
{
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]];
    //NSLog(@"tapped it %lf", location.x);
    if(location.x<=105){
        //1st 3rd tapped, do something

    }
    else if(location.x >105 && location.x<=210)
    {
       //do nothing, selected item stays same. this is glas
    }else{
       //must be in 3rd section so do that load

    }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You just check if ios7 then setFrame again inside

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController